# Cron job scheduler and authentication with expiring token using Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, cron

My Spring REST endpoint with Bearer token --> sends data to cron server --> sends data back to my server

My bearer token is with an expiry time of 10 Days. Let's say I am sending a request to the cron server on the 9th day and the cron server request to be executed after 2 days(9+2 = 11) my bearer token will gets expire on the 10th day only and hence cron server will never get authenticated by my server.

Is there any way to handle this situation or I am missing something? Can you please help me?

I am using 'set cronjob as scheduler and Spring Boot for creating my own custom REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Spring Scheduler for cron system and RPC management for the replying system,
if it could help you there is some link below from baeldung and another from RabbitMQ ( if you want you could use Apache Kafka or ActiveMQ to replace it but I suggest you to check your needs before choosing one ) :

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

You could use websocket too for the replying system:
https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

[EDIT]I don't know If I've misunderstanding your situation, may I've bad reading sorry
if it's time issue why you couldn't just send the token on the 8th day ?

Elsewhere if you can manage the cron server you can do send more information like the date when you send the token

Comment: Thanks for the reply. RE: why you couldn't just send the token on the 8th day - My REST API authenticate every incoming request with token. So if cron is executed after token has expired, my server never gets request from cron.